# Smaller file size for Audio-Record Ogg profile?

Tags: sound, audio-recording, ogg-vorbis

I would like to create a new recording profile for [Audio Recorder](https://launchpad.net/~audio-recorder).

The one I currently use is the following:

**ogg, CD Quality, Lossy 44KHz**

```
audio/x-raw,rate=44100,channels=2 ! vorbisenc name=enc quality=0.5 ! oggmux
```

However, it creates files that are too large. How do I need to modify `rate`, `channels` and `quality` to achieve smaller file sizes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To manipulate the size of your output file you will need to modify the `quality` settings (leave `rate` and `channels` as they are). The GStreamer `vorbisenc` 'allowed' settings range from -0.1 to 1:

1. **-0.1** = lowest quality and smallest file size
2. **1** = highest quality and largest file size

Just a matter of experimenting a little and finding the right balance for your system and for your ears...

**References:**

- [GStreamer Docs: vorbisenc](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-base-plugins/html/gst-plugins-base-plugins-vorbisenc.html)